# How to split a fine-tuned huggingface transformer model into two networks?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I´m working on a framework where I have multiple text classification tasks (as shown in the example for binary text classification). For these tasks I´m using the powerful [huggingface-transformer library](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). My code looks actually like this for the binary classification task.

```
class BertForBinaryDocumentClassification(BertPreTrainedModel):

def __init__(self, config):
    super().__init__(config)
    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(in_features=config.hidden_size, out_features=config.num_labels)
    self.init_weights()

def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=None,head_mask=None, labels=None):
    outputs = self.bert(input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, head_mask=head_mask)
    pooled_output = outputs[0]
    pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
    logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

    outputs = (logits,) + outputs[2:]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here

    loss_fct = BCELoss()
    loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
    outputs = (loss,) + outputs

    return outputs  # (loss), logits, (hidden_states), (attentions)
```

Now I´m takle performance problems because for each classifiction task I use the whole BERT model with the proper classification head (binary and multiclass). One model is about 400-500Mb.

Now I´m wondering if I could split these networks in the BERT model, which produces the sentence embedding and send these encoded sentence embeddings to standalone classification networks with the final linear layer as shown in the code below.

The problem is now that I´m not really sure how to tackle this problem. I was reading of freezing the last layer and send the intermediate embedding to the classification network. One thing is that I wonder if it still represents the whole information of the BERT layers from 1 to 11?

Another thing is that I´m not really sure how the standalone classification layer should look like. I think it should look like this way.

```
class BinaryClassifier(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, context_size):
    super(BinaryClassifier, self).__init__()
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(in_features=config.hidden_size, out_features=config.num_labels)
    self.init_weights()

def forward(self, inputs):
    embeds = self.embeddings(inputs).view((1, -1))
    logits = self.classifier(embeds)
    outputs = (logits,) + outputs[2:]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here

    loss_fct = BCELoss()
    loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
    outputs = (loss,) + outputs

    return outputs  # (loss), logits, (hidden_states), (attentions)
```

Can anybody tell me if my approach is correct and if not how to tackle this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you finetuned BERT or just the classification head? Is a multihead model also a potential solution for you?

Comment: I finetuned BERT for sequence classification but loaded the pretrained BERT model. So yes, I just finetuned the classification head.

Multihead sounds interesting. I did not take this into account. I will have a look at it.

Comment: I will take a look at it and will post my attemp tomorrow. Would be nice if you can correct it if its the wrong way. :)